# Como separo um banco de dados em vários através de filtros em um campo no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um banco de dados onde a populaçao são os funcionários da empresa e uma das colunas da base de categorias sao DIRETORES. Preciso selecionar um diretor específico e na coluna GERENTES (dentro do diretor escolhido) selecionar 1 gerente.
Com essa seleção gostaria que fosse criado um banco de dados novo separado por gerente.
Farei isso para cada gerente  do diretor selecionado.
Quando terminar, preciso selecionar outro diretor e fazer a mesma operacao até criar todas as bases por cada gerente que está dentro de cada diretoria.

Comment: `base-sep <- split(base, list(base$DIRETORES, base$GERENTES))`?

Comment: Poderia incluir um exemplo de como são seus dados e o resultado desejado? Não precisam ser dados reais.

Comment: @RuiBarradas muito obrigada! É exatamente isso que preciso. E poderia me dizer como salvo as bases criadas após seu comando em excel?

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta muito obrigada pela sua atenção. Mas o comando do Rui é exatamente oq eu preciso.

Answer (score 1):

Com o pedido de como escrever a base depois de separada em ficheiro Excel, o meu comentário acima passa a resposta.

Primeiro cria-se uma base exemplo, depois separa-se a base por `DIRETOR` e `GERENTE`, finalmente escreve-se a base em ficheiro Excel com a função `writexl::write_xlsx`.

```r
# Base exemplo
set.seed(2022)
base <- data.frame(DIRETORES = rep(1:6, 4),
                   GERENTES = rep(rep(1:4, each = 3), 2),
                   VALOR1 = rnorm(24),
                   VALOR2 = runif(24))

# Separar a base por DIRETOR e por GERENTE
base_sep <- split(base, list(base$DIRETORES, base$GERENTES))
# Ordenar por DIRETOR e GERENTE
base_sep <- base_sep[order(names(base_sep))]

# Opcional
# estas instruções acrescentam prefixos 
#   'D' - DIRETOR
#   'G' - GERENTE
# aos nomes dos membros da lista base_sep
# Esses nomes serão os nomes das folhas do ficheiro Excel
names(base_sep) <- sub("^", "D", names(base_sep))
names(base_sep) <- sub("\\.", ".G", names(base_sep))
names(base_sep)
#>  [1] "D1.G1" "D1.G2" "D1.G3" "D1.G4" "D2.G1" "D2.G2" "D2.G3" "D2.G4" "D3.G1"
#> [10] "D3.G2" "D3.G3" "D3.G4" "D4.G1" "D4.G2" "D4.G3" "D4.G4" "D5.G1" "D5.G2"
#> [19] "D5.G3" "D5.G4" "D6.G1" "D6.G2" "D6.G3" "D6.G4"

# Escrever o ficheiro Excel
writexl::write_xlsx(base_sep, path = "~/tmp/so_pt_exemplo.xlsx")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Rui, obrigada mais uma vez! Fiz como você me passou mas na hora de exportar para o excel está dando erro.

Seguem meus codigos:

**base_teste1 <- split(base_teste, list(base_teste$DIRETOR, base_teste$Gerente))**        base_teste1 <- base_teste1[order(names(base_teste1))]  **install.packages("writexl")**      
library(writexl)  
**writexl::write_xlsx(base_teste1, path = "~/tmp/base_final.xlsx")**

Comment: Após esse comando do writexl está apresentando erro no R: **_[ERROR] workbook_close(): Error creating 'C:\Users\LUCIANAFERREIRAWERNE\Documents\tmp\base_final.xlsx'. System error = No such file or directory
Error: Error in libxlsxwriter: 'Error creating output xlsx file. Usually a permissions error.'_**

Comment: @Luw O diretório `"~/tmp"` existe no meu computador, no seu escolha o `path` que quiser e tente outra vez.